# Sequence $x_n= \frac{a^n + b^n}{(ab)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Verify if the sequence

$$x_n=\frac{a^n + b^n}{(ab)^n}$$

converges, assuming $ab>1$ and $a,b>0$.

My attempt:

If $ a+b<ab$, then the sequence is convergent, since, if we consider the series

$$\sum x_n$$

Then, since $(a+b)^n > a^n + b^n,$ by the root test the series

$$\sum  (\frac{a+b}{ab})^n $$ converges

But I don't know how to use the hypothesis that $ab>1 $ and to show the other case.
I would be glad if I could have some help doing it. You don't need to consider what I made, if not needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b=4$. The resulting sequence diverges (to $\infty$).

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking if the sequence $x_n$ converges or if the series $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x_n$ converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of simplification gives $x_n = \frac{1}{a^n} + \frac{1}{b^n}$. Suppose $|a| < |b|$ (and $a, b\not = 0$; the case $a = -b$ is easy). Then there exists some constant $0 < \epsilon < 1$ such that $|b^{-n}| < \epsilon |a^{-n}|$. It follows that
$$(1 - \epsilon) \sum \frac{1}{a^n} \leq \sum x_n \leq (1 + \epsilon)\sum \frac{1}{a^n}.$$
Thus $\sum x_n$ converges iff $\sum \frac{1}{a^n}$ converges; that is, iff $|a| > 1$.

Comment: What about the hypotesis ab>1?

Comment: It doesn't work. Take $a = 4, b = 1/2$, for example. Then $x_1 + \cdots + x_n \geq 1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^n = 2^{n+1} - 1$.

Comment: It is only a hypotesis the the problem gave, I am not saying it is a condition for convergence. I am asking if it is not necessary

Comment: By the way, why does the  existance of the constant $C$ is guarantee?

Comment: If $a, b > 0$, then the sequence converges iff $\min(a, b) > 1$; just taking $ab > 1$ is not sufficient.

Comment: Again, I am NOT saying it is sufficient, it is just a HYPOTESIS that the problem gave, but it seems it is not necessary.

Comment: If you assume from the beginning that $a, b > 0$, then you need $a, b > 1$. It follows from $a, b> 1$ that $ab > 1$, but I'm not sure what the latter is supposed to get you in the proof.

Comment: Are you considering the series $\sum x_n$ instead of the sequence $(x_n)$?

Comment: @user84413: Oh, that's a good point. I thought we were talking about the former. If it's the latter, you just need (for $a, b > 0$, at least) the seqeunce $a^{-n}$ and $b^{-n}$ to converge. It also turns out that $a, b \geq 1$ (not $> 1$ as above) is necessary and sufficient in that case.

Comment: You're right - I just didn't want the OP to confuse the two problems.

Answer (score 5):

If $a = 3$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}$, then $ab = \frac{3}{2} > 1$ and $a,b > 0$.

However, $x_n = \dfrac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^n} = \dfrac{3^n+\frac{1}{2^n}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^n} = 2^n + \dfrac{1}{3^n}$ diverges.

Hence, the conditions for convergence that you wrote down are not correct.

---

Notice that $x_n = \dfrac{a^n+b^n}{(ab)^n} = \dfrac{a^n}{(ab)^n}+\dfrac{b^n}{(ab)^n} = \dfrac{1}{b^n}+\dfrac{1}{a^n}$.

Hence, if $a,b > 0$ then $x_n$ converges if $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$.

Comment: By thw way, in your example, $a+b > ab$, and I said that we need to have $a+b < ab$. This does not prove that what I did was wrong, then.

Comment: Your statement that "$x_n$ converges if $a+b < ab$" isn't wrong, but the condition $a \ge 1$ and $b \ge 1$ is less restrictive than $a+b < ab$. Consider for instance $a = b = \frac{3}{2}$. The series converges, but $a+b > ab$.

Comment: yes, I see. As I said, it was just an attempt. The anomaly answer looks even more general